# How to create a custom route when calling an action using form_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, custom-routes

I created custom routes '/album' that routes to 'microposts#new'. However, when I use a form_for it routes to '/micropost' instead of returning to '/album'.

In my controller I'm using render 'album'. I would prefer to keep as render, although I can make it work using redirect_to.

I know the problem is when I'm calling the create action in my micropost controller, it goes to /micropost instead of /album. Still new to rails and help would be appreciated.

Here is routes.rb:

```
  root 'pages#home'

  get '/album',       to: 'microposts#new'
  post '/album',      to: 'microposts#create'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `url: "/album"` as an additional parameter in the form_for.

For additional options, see the [doc](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for).